# Add Navigation Drawer fragment to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I want to add my Navigation Drawer fragment to activity, but I want that the activity layout "behind" Navigation Drawer will stay the same.

What i got
[image]

Without open Navigation Drawer
[image: Without open Navigation Drawer<br>]

What I want 
[image]

**Navigation Drawer fragment activity XML**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
        android:layout_gravity="start">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/logoBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            android:padding="8dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/g4aLogo"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/settingsList"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/logoBox"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:background="#ffffffff" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**activity XML**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/searchBarLay"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


//CONTENTS and layouts...


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity code part when I implement Navigation Drawer**

```
private void initSettingsDrawer() {
        Button settingsDrawerButton =(Button)findViewById(R.id.settingsDrawer);
        settingsDrawerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SettingsDrawer settingsDrawer = new SettingsDrawer();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_main, settingsDrawer).commit();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout should be the parent/root layout. Your xml should be like this,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
    android:layout_gravity="start">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/logoBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:padding="8dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/g4aLogo"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/settingsList"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logoBox"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="#ffffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: When i remove the relative layout from xml i got error: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY error. Should I create custom DrawerLayout and then it will work?

Comment: I made Custom and get rid of error but removing Relative Layout form DrawerLayout XML does not solve my issue ( still i have blank space behind the navigation Drawer

Comment: update screen shots with and without navigation drawer.

Comment: in your fragment add this line
"drawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));"

Comment: still nothing. I also tried set transparent background into XML file

Answer (score 0):

Add this library to your build.gradle file

compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.1.3@aar') {
        transitive = true }

And then add this code in your Activity where you want the navigation drawer.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Drawer result = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    AccountHeader headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
           // .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.nav_header)

            .addProfiles(
                    new ProfileDrawerItem().withEmail("abc@gmail.com").withIcon(getResources().
                            getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            )
            .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean currentProfile) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .build();

    result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
            .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
            .build();
    result.addItem(new PrimaryDrawerItem()
            .withName(("Home")).withIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
                    withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }));
    result.addItem(new PrimaryDrawerItem()
            .withName(("Settings")).withIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
                    withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }));

}
```

}

Comment: i rather use the solution that not take external libraries moreover I would like to implement my navigation Driver to several independend acitvites and I dont want repeating code in each of them